# such a good show that

Tags: meaning, clauses

Which are correct:

1. It was such a good show that everyone loved it.
2. It was a good show, such that everyone loved it.

Is there any difference in the meanings?

Comment: #2 is "valid", but incredibly unlikely. And it doesn't mean quite the same thing anyway. #1 means everyone loved the show *because* it was so good, but #2 would mean something like *The **way** in which the show was good was such (of a type) that everyone loved it*.